# Excel VBA - Why is my cell value not being appended?

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a script (See Below) that adds the contents of every cell in the used rows to another cell in a different worksheet. However, this works for the first 3 cells but will not work for the last 2 for some reason.

```
Sub Ready_For_Infra()
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("InfraData")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("ActionPlan")

ws1.Cells.Clear

For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
    For k = 1 To ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With Worksheets("InfraData")
            If ws2.Cells(k, i).Value <> "" Then
            ws1.Range("A" & i).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value & ws2.Cells(i, k).Value & Chr(10)
            End If
        End With
    Next k
Next i

MsgBox "Done"



End Sub
```

This is the data in ws2 (ActionPlan) just in case it helps:

[image: Example of Data I am transferring]

To clarify, it doesn't appear to be appending Cells D2:F3 to the cells I have asked it to. Is anyone able to advise why this might be the case?

Comment: try to change `If ws2.Cells(k, i).Value <> "" Then` to `If ws2.Cells(i, k).Value <> "" Then`

Comment: You don't need to explicitly state that you want to step by one.

Comment: @simoco That did the trick, I don't know why I ever had it that way round as the second part is the correct way.

Comment: @Petay87, also look into [Application.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264098(v=office.15).aspx) function - it can help you to join your values without second loop.

Comment: @simoco I am happy to accept that as an answer if you would like so that this is not left as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Ready_For_Infra()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim str1 As String

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("InfraData")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("ActionPlan")

    ws1.Cells.Clear

    With ws2
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            str1 = ""
            For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, lastcol))
                If cell.Value <> "" Then str1 = str1 & cell.Value & Chr(10)
            Next cell
            ws1.Range("A" & i).Value = str1
        Next i
    End With

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. using `For each` loop is slightly faster then `For k=1 To lastcol`
2. using temporary string variable `str1` makes your code faster as well, because in that case you writes result value in `ws1.Range("A" & i)` cell only once (working with operating memory is always faster than writing subresult in cell for each iteration).

Comment: That is a lot easier to read than my novice Jargon! Is there an easy way to get the For Each loop to skip Column D & E?

Comment: you can use sth like this: `If cell.Column<>4 And cell.Column<>5 And cell.Value <> "" Then`

Comment: would I be able to do it in reverse order if I did For i = Lastrow To 2 and did previous i at the end of the loop?

Comment: sure, just add `Step -1` like this: `For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1`

Comment: I now have For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1 but it appears that it is going from row 2 to the last row rather than going in reverse.

Comment: ah, and also change `ws1.Range("A" & i).Value = str1` to `ws1.Range("A" & 2 + lastrow - i).Value = str1`